# Material-UI Select e.target.value is undefined

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Material-UI's Select component in one of my React projects. I require the dropdown data to be shown in groups, hence I'm using `<MenuItem>` wrapped around `<ListSubheader>`. I'm having a hard time getting the value of my `MenuItem`s. Please let me know if there's anything blatantly wrong with my code.

```js
<FormControl>
    <InputLabel>Product type</InputLabel>
    <Select
    id="product-type"
    input={<Input id="grouped-select" />}
    value={this.state.productType}
    autoWidth={true}
    style={{ width: 200 }}
    onChange={(e, child) => {
        console.log(e.target.value); // undefined!
    }}
    >
    {this.state.productList.map((p, i) => {
        const list = p[1];

        let items = list.map((e, j) => {
        return (
            <MenuItem key={j} value={e.name}>
            {e.name}
            </MenuItem>
        );
        });

        return (
        <div>
            <ListSubheader key={i}>{p[0]}</ListSubheader>
            {items}
        </div>
        );
    })}
    </Select>
</FormControl>
```

Comment: try this onChange={handleChange} and the function is const handleChange = event => {
    setAge(event.target.value);
  };

Comment: can you console.log `this.state.productList` and tell us the value? Also is your data coming from an api?

Comment: @AtinSingh Yes, it's coming from an API and the data is actually there. Looks something like this:

`
[
  [
    "Garments",
    [
      {
        "pk": 2,
        "master_category": {
          "pk": 1,
          "name": "Garments"
        },
        "name": "T-Shirts"
      }
    ]
  ]
]
`

Comment: @GauravRoy I have tried creating a handleChange function, however, e.target.value is still undefined.

Comment: It's an array or arrays?

Comment: @AtinSingh it's an array of arrays. The first element is the Subheader of the dropdown. The dropdown contents are rendered properly with the data shown as expected. It's just that I cannot get the value of out it. 

It looks something like: [[Garments, [{T-shirts}, {Dresses}, {Trousers}], [Accessories, [{Bags}, {Wallets}], ...]

Comment: Okay, I haven't used material ui much but are you sure you can have other components aside from `MenuItem` inside `<Select>` component?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202625/discussion-between-kkmonlee-and-atin-singh).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason `e.target.value` was returning undefined was, as others mentioned, due to the fact that `MenuItem` wasn't a direct child of `Select`. Since `productList` is dynamically being set into the dropdown, it has to be rendered in such a way:

```
ListSubheader0
   Item0
   Item1
ListSubheader1
   Item2
   Item3
   Item4
   ...
...
```

Instead of wrapping my `ListSubheader` and `MenuItem` in a `div` tag where reading the `target.value` was impossible, I returned an array.

```js
return [
    <ListSubheader key={i}>
        {p[0]}
    </ListSubheader>, 
    items
];
```

Comment: This was true in my case. I had a <div> wrapping the menu-items, so that I could apply styling using css. Now I was able to fix the value in the select component, but I need to figure out how to fix the styling! Thanks for your answer though!

Answer (score 0):

Material-ui Select direct children must be MenuItem:

> ⚠️The MenuItem elements must be direct descendants when native is
>   false.

You need to change your code accordingly so `MenuItem` is direct child of `Select`. Something like:

```
<MenuItem key={i} value={p[0]}>
    <ListSubheader key={i}>{p[0]}</ListSubheader>
    {items}
</MenuItem>
```

It may look different, but `e.target.value` will not be undefined now.

Comment: This would make my Subheader "selectable" if that makes sense. My objective is to keep my dropdown the same way as it is now (Subheader0 -> Items relevant, Subheader1 -> Items relevant, ...)